# Join next lines with space or semicolumn seperated till it matches the pattern

Tags: shell, unix, awk, scripting

I am looking for an output something like below.

```
Data for SUDO 'touch'
    test           (GROUP  ) X
    users           (GROUP  ) X
Comment           : /usr/bin/touch
Data for SUDO 'wc'
    test           (GROUP  ) X
Comment           : /usr/bin/wc
Data for SUDO 'reclaim-files'
Comment           : /etc/uidchanges/reclaim-files;;
```

My output should be:

```
Data for SUDO 'touch'+    test           (GROUP  ) X+    users           (GROUP  ) X+Comment           : /usr/bin/touch
Data for SUDO 'wc'+    test           (GROUP  ) X;Comment           : /usr/bin/wc
Data for SUDO 'reclaim-files'+Comment           : /etc/uidchanges/reclaimfiles;;
```

Comment: looks like the data i posted doesnt got well to everyone's view, what is want is all lines below "Data for sudo" till next "Data for sudo" should join the line Data for SUDO with some "+" delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this awk one-liner does the job:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",(NR>1&&/^Data for SU/?RS:""),$0}END{print ""}' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
Data for SUDO 'touch'
    test           (GROUP  ) X
    users           (GROUP  ) X
Comment           : /usr/bin/touch
Data for SUDO 'wc'
    test           (GROUP  ) X
Comment           : /usr/bin/wc
Data for SUDO 'reclaim-files'
Comment           : /etc/uidchanges/reclaim-files;;

kent$  awk '{printf "%s%s",(NR>1&&/^Data for SU/?RS:""),$0}END{print ""}' f
Data for SUDO 'touch'    test           (GROUP  ) X    users           (GROUP  ) XComment           : /usr/bin/touch
Data for SUDO 'wc'    test           (GROUP  ) XComment           : /usr/bin/wc
Data for SUDO 'reclaim-files'Comment           : /etc/uidchanges/reclaim-files;;
```

Comment: that was really awesome thank you verrrrrrrrrryyyyy much Kent. By the way it didnt work on Solaris machine, i had to switch to Linux machine to get the output..Anyways i am good. But if you could get me working in solaris that would be great too..

In solaris i get the below.
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

And could you please tell me whats your command does.

Comment: I don't have solaris, cannot test it for you.  Here is brief explanation: `printf` doesn't output newline (linebreak), we check if there was `Data for SUDO`, output a newline then text followed. in this way, the awk codes do what you want. The last `END{print ""}` is just add a newline to the end, so that your last line ending with newline character. If this answer solved your problem, pls mark it as accepted answer. @Binish

Comment: thank Kent, appreciate you quick response.